# How can I autofold POD in Perl with vim?

Tags: perl, vim, folding

I'm trying to edit files with vim and get the POD automatically folded (just the POD, not the Perl). I can't get it to work. I can get folding itself to work because I can manually highlight the lines and type `zF` and it folds properly.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot

```
:set foldmethod=syntax
:setf perl
:syntax on
:set foldenable
:syn region POD start=/^=head[123]/ end=/^=cut/ fold
```

Comment: It only works if I fail to load my .vimrc.  Regrettably, I can't figure out how to debug what's causing the conflict.  Still, it's a step closer.  Thanks!

Comment: Comment out half the file.  If it works, the problem is in that half.
Repeat.

Comment: @jrockway D'oh!  I'll have to do that with my plugins, too.  Those are the ones which will be a pain, but yeah, I'll figure out how to get this working :)

Comment: dont load your vimrc file, then after you get into vim, use- ":debug source ~/.vimrc" which will step-debug you through the entire thing, you can step over stuff you dont want to go into (like other sources, plugins, etc). This is the best way I know of to debug vim scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the following at the *end* of your ~/.vimrc file:

```
fu! MyFoldSettings()
  set foldmethod=expr
  set foldexpression=MyFoldLevel(v:lnum)
  set foldenable
  set foldminlines=1
endf      

fu! MyFoldLevel(lev)
    let mytext = getline(a:lev)
    let result="="
    if mytext =~ '^=item'
        let result=">3"
    elsei mytext =~ '^=back'
        let result="<2"
    elsei mytext =~ '^=over'
        let result=">2"
    elsei mytext =~ '^=cut'
        let result="<1"
    elsei mytext =~ '^=\w\+'
        let result='>1'
    en    
    return result
endf

augroup MyFoldSettings_AutoCommands
   au!
   au BufReadPost {*.pl,*.pod,*.pm} MyFoldSettings()
augroup END
```

This should work in most cases -- It's just a quick and dirty example, but you can add more too it if you need more functionality. Also, to make certain that this is enabled you might want to add the modeline:

```
# vim:fen:fdo=hor:fcl=all:fdm=expr:fde=MyFoldLevel(v:lnum):fml=1
```

If you dont see folded text at this point, try setting the 'foldopen=hor' and 'foldclose=all' which will make navigation into/out of folds easier. Also, if you need this to be applied to other files or filetyps, you can set up the au (autocommand) accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your .vimrc:

```
au FileType perl
    \ setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^=cut'?'<1':getline(v:lnum)=~'^='?'1':'=' |
    \ setlocal foldmethod=expr
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define perl_fold_* variables, the system perl syntax highlighter will take care of the rest.

In .vimrc, just add

```
let perl_fold=1
let perl_fold_blocks=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using,

```
set syntax                                                                                                                                                               

augroup perl_folding                                                                                                                                                     
    au!                                                                                                                                                                  
    autocmd FileType perl setlocal foldmethod=syntax                                                                                                                     
    autocmd FileType perl setlocal foldlevel=1                                                                                                                           
    autocmd FileType perl let perl_fold = 1                                                                                                                              
    autocmd FileType perl let perl_fold_blocks = 1                                                                                                                       
    autocmd FileType perl setlocal foldenable                                                                                                                            
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pm set filetype=perl                                                                                                                         
augroup END
```